# Как нарисовать тор в OpenGL?

Tags: графика, геометрия, opengl

Как нарисовать тор в OpenGL без использования устаревших функций и, конечно, без заготовок типа GLUT и так далее?

Comment: Ну если без ГЛУТ, то ищите математическое выражение, описывающее тор и рендите по нему. Ну или создайте 3Д модел тора в спец. редакторе и рендите модель.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Параметрически тор описывается следующим набором уравнений:

- *x(theta, phi) = (R + r * cos(phi)) * cos(theta)*
- *y(theta, phi) = (R + r * cos(phi)) * sin(theta)*
- *z(theta, phi) = r * sin(phi)*

R - раcстояние от оси тора до центра образующей окружности, r - радиус образующей окружности.

Определитесь какой уровень детализации вам нужен и в двух циклах (по *phi* и по *theta*, один из циклов вложен в другой) итерируйтесь с нужным шагом от *0* до *2***PI* и вычисляйте координаты вершин. Чем меньше шаг, тем выше будет количество вершин и детализация тора.

Когда у вас будет массив координат, вы можете отрисовать его любым удобным способом.